# In C++, do dereferencing and getting index zero do the same tihng?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I just tried this code:

```
int i = 33;
int * pi = &i;
cout << "i: " << *pi << endl;
cout << "i: " << pi[0] << endl;
```

Both lines return the same thing.

Essentially, if I get index zero of any pointer, I'll get the value of the correct type at the location of the pointer. Isn't that the same thing as dereferencing?

Every time a pointer is dereferenced in C++, wouldn't getting index zero also work? I'm not suggesting anyone should actually *do* that, but I think it would *work*. Wouldn't it?

Comment: I should think so, but I'm not sure. Unleash the language lawyers.

Comment: That's true in C. That's true in C++ if you don't overload operators.

Comment: When **pi=&i** to get i back use __*pi__ .  You have *pi = &i , which is double indirection.

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays#Pointers_and_Arrays

Comment: @ArifBurhan - no, `int *pi = &i;` is a **definition** of `pi` as a **pointer to int**. It also **initializes** `pi` with the address of `i`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ignoring overloaded operators, there's one case there is a difference, and that's array rvalues post-[DR1213](http://wg21.link/cwg1213):

```
using arr = int[2];
arr&& f();
int&& b = *f(); // error, *f() is an lvalue, doesn't bind to int&&
int&& c = f()[0]; // OK, subscript applied to array rvalue results in an xvalue
```

I don't know of any compiler that implements that resolution, though. But it should be implemented eventually.

Comment: ＋1. I just realized that I did not quote `5.2.1` completely. Corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming no operator overloading, they are nearly the same.

**[C] 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**:

> `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

**[C++] 5.2.1 Subscripting**:

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))` ...  , except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an
>   lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

See the great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559374/3246555) of **@T.C** regarding the last part.

Comment: Nice to see the actual reference to the standard. Does that mean that `E1[E2]` is the same as `E2[E1]`?

Comment: @T.C. Oh, indeed! Corrected. BTW, the downvote arrived _before_ I edited and added the first sentence ).

Comment: Off in a dark corner of the Internet sits a person chortling gleefully. "One down, 17,710 to go..."

Comment: @flatmouse Yes, E1[E2] is the same as E2[E1]. Again, if no special cases  take place. (Meaning you can write 1[a] instead of a[1].)

Answer (score 4):

For pointers, they should give the same result.

The only time that they could differ is if you are applying them on a user-defined type that overloads `operator*()` and `operator[](int)` differently (or one and not the other, in which case you would get a compile error).